# How to concatenate a Series of lists of str with a Series of str

Tags: python, pandas

Starting with a `Series` of lists of strings and a `Series` of strings, create a `Series` of lists where each element of each list is concatenated with the corresponding element of the second `Series`.

For example,

```
series1 = pd.Series([['a','b','c'],['d','e']])
series2 = pd.Series(['1','2'])
```

so that `series3` looks like:

```
0   [a1, b1, c1]
1       [d2, e2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with columns of lists in pandas, you have already decided to forfeit performance. Here's as fast an approach as you'd probably get, using a *list comprehension*.

```
pd.Series(
    [[k + j for k in i] for i, j in zip(series1, series2)]
) 

0    [a1, b1, c1]
1        [d2, e2]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Perfect!  Just a little context here which may provide a simpler answer. What I'm starting with is a `Series` of sentences which I `.str.split()` into individual words that I want to concatenate with a Series of strings.

Comment: @TedTo You could choose to open another question with your actual input (few rows only, please!) and ask how best to do it.

Comment: Hmm.  In my actual application I'm finding that the concatenated `Series` are not in the same order as the original `Series`.

Comment: @TedTo I can tell you straightaway that isn't because of this code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're claiming this. `series1 = df.sentence.str.split()` is a `Series` of lists as I specified.  Applying your code gives me a new `Series` of lists but not in the same order.

Comment: @TedTo There is nothing here to randomize/interchange/shuffle the order. `zip` retains order. Lists retain order. String concatenation doesn't do anything either. Can you please provide a [mcve] with the data that causes this problem?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  What was happening is that the indexes on `series1` and `series2` are not 0, 1, 2,...  But the new `Series` **is** indexed 0, 1, 2,... so that when putting them together, the new series gets reordered.

Comment: @TedTo okay, that's helpful to know for future reference, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By using `add`

```
series1.apply(pd.Series).stack().add(series2.astype(str),level=0).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
Out[83]: 
0    [a1, b1, c1]
1        [d2, e2]
dtype: object
```